# javascript - need sone advice

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

hi there I need a little help with this. I am working on a webpage and need to access combobox's selected text but my combobox is in one iframe and my function is in other iframe.
there is structure of website

**index.html**

```
<div id="banner">...</div> <!-- banner -->
<div id="navigation">...</div> <!-- navigation -->
<div id="main">
    <iframe id="MainFrame" name="MainFrame" src="./core/core.php"></iframe>
</div> <!-- main -->
<div id="footer">...</div> <!-- footer -->
```

in `#MainFrame` I load document with other iframes - when i click on my menu Shop loads shop_index.html

**shop_index.html**

```
<div id="mainContainer">
   <div id="toolBar">
      <iframe id="ToolBar" name="ToolBar" src="toolbar.php"></iframe>
   </div>
   <div id="container">
     <div id="leftTree">...</div>
     <div id="items">
        <iframe id="ItemsFrame" name="ItemsFrame" src="items.php"></iframe>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

So in `items.php` I want to get and to use selected text/value from combobox located in `toolbar.php`. I hope someone can help me.

I tried to solve it using jQuery but didn't work.

Comment: You should use `<?php include('myfile.php'); ?>`
It avoids the use of iframes, if you just use it to include parts of your page  :)

Comment: each file has functions to generate tables/list/menus from mysql databse and i put iframes to build my menu - load each page in MainFrame with <a href="page.php" target="MainFrame">

Answer (score 0):

Frames are really not the best way to program, there are better ways, but you need to reference the parent, than the iframe to get the contents.

```
window.parent.$("#ToolBar").contents().find("#elementToFind").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   window.parent.$("#ToolBar").contents().find("#elementToFind").val();
```

is not working but i found other way with href links

```
href="items.php?itemid=101010&price=100" target="ItemsFrame"
```

and

```
$_GET['itemid'] $_GET['price']
```